# Visual Studio DebuggerStepThrough for Property Setter

Tags: c#, visual-studio, properties

I do not want to disable Visual Studio's normal handling of all exceptions. I am looking for a way to ignore the exceptions raised by the setter of a specific property. I am aware of `[DebuggerNonUserCode]` and `[DebuggerStepThrough]`, but they don't seem to be applicable to properties, or more specifically setters.

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you provide a quick sample of using that attribute?

Comment: The `[DebuggerStepThrough]`? Did you check google? http://abhijitjana.net/2010/09/22/tips-on-debugging-using-debuggerstepthrough-attribute/

Comment: I'm curious if you're applying it to the property or the individual accessors

Comment: Neither worked, visual studio gave the error that they can only be applied to classes and methods.

Comment: Accessors are methods. I think that's your problem.  I'll post an answer

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I believe the problem you're running into is you're attempting to apply the attribute to the property instead of the individual accessors.  The accessors are the actual methods and where the attribute needs to go.  For example

```
int Property {
  [DebuggerNonUserCode]
  get { ... }
  [DebuggerNonUserCode]
  set { ... }
}
```